# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' belongs to a different Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to create an Realm object and getting «**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' belongs to a different Realm.**» exception.

I am using Realm.getDefaultInstance() that I've initiated in Fragment at OnCreateView.

The object I am trying to save into database uses other RealmObject as argument.

Code as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
    final ProductList productList = 
        realm.where(ProductList.class).equalTo("name", listName)
        .findFirst();
    ListEntry.create(realm, listId, productToAdd);
}
```

ListEntry.create looks like this —

```
public static void create(Realm realm,
                          final long listId,
                          final Product product,) {
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Parent parent = realm.where(Parent.class).findFirst();
        RealmList<ListEntry> entries = parent.getListEntries();
        ListEntry listEntry = realm.createObject(ListEntry.class, decrement());
        listEntry.setListId(listId);
        listEntry.setProduct(product);
        entries.add(listEntry);)
}
```

Parent.class is an abstraction I use to store list of all saved entries in Lists as it is done in Realm android's adapters example (https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/model/Parent.java).

Whenever I try to save the entry at onQueryTextSubmit it returns the error, not saving a thing.

This error message is extremely ungoogleable — thus I request your help.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I were writing the questoin for SO I found out the solution — instead of passing RealmObject as argument I just put id of the object there and added the object to the private RealmList inside the Object during transaction.

So, instead of —

```
ListEntry.class:
@PrimaryKey
private long entryId; 
private Product product;
```

I wrote

```
@PrimaryKey
private long entryId; 
private RealmList<Product> productArray;
```

and inside a transaction —

```
Product product = realm.where(Product.class).equalTo("productId", productId).findFirst();
listEntry.getProductArray().add(product);
```

And now everything works. Zero-copy design at it's finest.

Keeping it here for those others unfortunate with the google search.